# Waterlogged iPod Touch

Tags: ipod-touch, damage

A few years back, I accidentally jumped in the pool with my third gen iPod touch still in my pocket. I placed it in rice for a while, and it started working again, but the screen was extremely dull. Every day after that that I used it, the screen steadily got worse and worse to the point where I couldn't even tell what the background was anymore. Since then, it has sat untouched. I plugged it in today, and the screen is static-y and grey and indistinguishable. It still functions, but I can only tell due to my own memory. Is it worth anything? If not, where could I properly dispose of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you interested in purchasing a new iPod Touch? If so, you could check out [Apple's Recycling Program](http://www.apple.com/recycling/ipod-cell-phone/).

**From Apple's website,**

> Bring your old iPod to an Apple Retail Store and receive a 10 percent
> discount on the purchase of a new iPod.*

I'm not exactly sure if you would qualify due to its screen, but it is definitely worth a shot. Take it an Apple Store and see if they will give you 10 percent off.

**From an Apple Discussion Board,**

> ... you can throw it away, bury it, smash it, take it to Apple as
> recycling, use it as a paperweight, leave it in a drawer, etc.

### Update

I just checked on Newton's Head, and they will offer you `$5.50` for an iPod Touch 3rd Generation, water-damaged with all original accessories.

So, it's not going to be worth that much.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. If the offer is that low, I may just take it to one of my local Target stores and recycle it there. Thanks again.